# convert 2D sparse matrix to 3D matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to convert the 2D sparse matrix to 3D matrix as i need to give it as the input the conv1d layer, which expects 3D tensor.

Here is the input for the conv1d layer.

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
other_features_train = hstack((X_train_state_ohe, X_train_teacher_ohe, X_train_grade_ohe, X_train_category_ohe, X_train_subcategory_ohe,X_train_price_norm,X_train_number_norm))
other_features_cv = hstack((X_cv_state_ohe, X_cv_teacher_ohe, X_cv_grade_ohe,X_cv_category_ohe,X_cv_subcategory_ohe,X_cv_price_norm,X_cv_number_norm))
other_features_test = hstack((X_test_state_ohe, X_test_teacher_ohe, X_test_grade_ohe,X_test_category_ohe,X_test_subcategory_ohe,X_test_price_norm,X_test_number_norm))

print(other_features_train.shape)
print(other_features_cv.shape)
print(other_features_test.shape)
```

shape of the train , cv and test data

```
(49041, 101)
(24155, 101)
(36052, 101)
```

This is my model architecture.

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

vec_size = 300

input_model_1 = Input(shape=(300,),name='essay')
embedding = Embedding(vocab_size_essay, vec_size, weights=[word_vector_matrix], input_length = max_length, trainable=False)(input_model_1)
lstm = LSTM(16)(embedding)
flatten_1 = Flatten()(lstm)

input_model_2 = Input(shape=(101, ),name='other_features')
conv_layer1 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(input_model_2)
conv_layer2 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(conv_layer1)
conv_layer3 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(conv_layer2)
flatten_2 = Flatten()(conv_layer3)

concat_layer = concatenate(inputs=[flatten_1, flatten_2],name='concat')

dense_layer_1 = Dense(units=32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense_layer_1')(concat_layer)

dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2)(dense_layer_1)

dense_layer_2 = Dense(units=32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense_layer_2')(dropout_1)

dropout_2 = Dropout(0.2)(dense_layer_2)

dense_layer_3 = Dense(units=32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense_layer_3')(dropout_2)

output = Dense(units=2, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='output')(dense_layer_3)

model_3 = Model(inputs=[input_model_1,input_model_2],outputs=output)
```

and am getting this error when am trying to give 2d array.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-44c8f6f0caa7> in <module>
      9 
     10 input_model_2 = Input(shape=(101, ),name='other_features')
---> 11 conv_layer1 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(input_model_2)
     12 conv_layer2 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(conv_layer1)
     13 conv_layer3 = Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='relu')(conv_layer2)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    810         # are casted, not before.
    811         input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
--> 812                                               self.name)
    813         graph = backend.get_graph()
    814         with graph.as_default(), backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    175                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    176                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 177                          str(x.shape.as_list()))
    178     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    179       ndim = x.shape.ndims

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 101]

model_3.summary()
model_3.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam()
```

Compile the model

```
model_3.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Fit the model

```
model_3.fit(train_features,y_train_ohe,batch_size=16,epochs=10,validation_data=(cv_features,y_cv_ohe))

train_features = [train_text, other_features_train]
cv_features = [cv_text, other_features_cv]
test_featues = [test_text, other_features_test]
```

Text Features

```
train_text = X_train['essay'].tolist()
cv_text = X_cv['essay'].tolist()
test_text = X_test['essay'].tolist()

token = Tokenizer()
token.fit_on_texts(train_text)

vocab_size_essay = len(token.word_index) + 1
print("No. of unique words = ", vocab_size_essay)

encoded_train_text = token.texts_to_sequences(train_text)
encoded_cv_text = token.texts_to_sequences(cv_text)
encoded_test_text = token.texts_to_sequences(test_text)

#print(encoded_test_text[:5])

max_length = 300

train_text = pad_sequences(encoded_train_text, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
cv_text = pad_sequences(encoded_cv_text, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
test_text = pad_sequences(encoded_test_text, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')

print("\n")
print(train_text.shape)
print(cv_text.shape)
print(test_text.shape)
```

shape of text features

```
No. of unique words =  41468


(49041, 300)
(24155, 300)
(36052, 300)
```

So, I want the reshape in

```
(49041,101,1) 
(24155,101,1) 
(36052,101,1)
```

Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: I don't think only reshape is your problem, provide the code where you get the error, also you have a 300 length input vector for other input, what about that?

Comment: I have already provided the code with the error message. ValueError: Error when checking input: expected other_features to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (49041, 101)

Comment: If only the reshape operation answers your question, check my answer however I doubt it will solve the issue.

Comment: A sparse matrix is always 2d; it can be made 3d.  It can be converted to a dense array, as with `M.toarray()` or `M.A`, and that can be reshaped.  But sparse matrix itself can't add a dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

The solution here demands clarity on a few concepts as follows. I will explain these concepts
in the following sections.

- what `keras` expects as inputs
- what kind of modifications could be done to your `keras` model to allow sparse input matrices
- converting a 2D `numpy` array to a 3D `numpy` array
- back-and-forth conversion between a sparse and a non-sparse (or, dense) array using

  - `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` for 2D `numpy` array
  - `sparse.COO` for 3D `numpy` array

### Using sparse matrices as input to `tf.keras` models

- One option is to convert your sparse input matrix into the non-sparse (dense) format using
  `todense()` method. This makes the matrix a regular `numpy` array. See kaggle discussion,
  [[3]](https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-demographics/discussion/22567) and [[4]](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification/discussion/18154).
- Another option is to write your own custom Layers for both sparse and dense inputs by
  subclassing `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class. See this article, [[2]](https://medium.com/dailymotion/how-to-design-deep-learning-models-with-sparse-inputs-in-tensorflow-keras-fd5e754abec1).
- It appears that `tensorflow.keras` now allows model training with sparse weights. So,
  somewhere it has the ability to handle sparsity. You may want to explore the documentation,
  [[1]](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/train_sparse_models) for this aspect.

### Adding a new-axis to a numpy array

You can add another axis to a numpy array using `np.newaxis` as follows.

```py
import numpy as np

## Make a 2D array
a2D = np.zeros((10,10))

# Make a few elements non-zero in a2D
aa = a2D.flatten()
aa[[0,13,41,87,98]] = np.random.randint(1,10,size=5)
a2D = aa.reshape(a2D.shape)

# Make 3D array from 2D array by adding another axis
a3D = a2D[:,:,np.newaxis]
#print(a2D)
print('a2D.shape: {}\na3D.shape: {}'.format(a2D.shape, a3D.shape))
```

**Output**:

```
a2D.shape: (10, 10)
a3D.shape: (10, 10, 1)
```

Having said that, please take a look at the links in the **References** section.

### Sparse Arrays

Since a sparse array has very few non-zero values, a regular numpy array when converted
into a sparse array, stores it in a few sparse-formats:

- `csr_matrix`: row-wise arrays of non-zero values and indices
- `csc-matrix`: column-wise array of nonzero values and indices
- `coo-matrix`: a table with three columns

  - row
  - column
  - non-zero value

**Scipy Sparse Matrices expect 2D input-matrix**

However, `scipy.sparse` implementation of the above three types of sparse-matrices, only
considers 2D non-sparse matrix as input.

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, coo_matrix

coo_a2D = coo_matrix(a2D)
coo_a2D.shape # output: (10, 10)

# scipy.sparse only accepts 2D input matrices
# the following line will throw an !!! ERROR !!!
coo_a3D = coo_matrix(coo_a2D.todense()[:,:,np.newaxis])
```

#### Sparse Matrix from 3D non-sparse input matrix

Yes, you can do this using the [`sparse`](https://github.com/pydata/sparse) library.
It also supports `scipy.sparse` and `numpy` arrays. To convert from sparse matrix to
non-sparse (dense) format (*this is NOT a Dense Layer in neural networks*), use
the `todense()` method.

```py
## Installation
# pip install -U sparse

import sparse

## Create sparse coo_matrix from a
# 3D numpy array (dense format)
coo_a3D = sparse.COO(a3D)

## Test that
#   coo_a3D == coo made from (coo_a2D + newaxis)
print(
    (coo_a3D == sparse.COO(coo_a2D.todense()[:,:,np.newaxis])).all()
) # output: True
## Convert to dense (non-sparse) format
#   use: coo_a3D.todense()
print((a3D == coo_a3D.todense()).all()) # output: True
```

[image: scipy.sparse.coo_matrix vs. sparse.COO]

[Source](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/)

#### PyTorch: `torch.sparse`  ⭐

PyTorch library also provides ways to work with sparce tensors.

- Documentation `torch.sparse`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html#sparse-coo-docs

  [image: warning: torch.sparse]

### References

1. [Train sparse TensorFlow models with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/train_sparse_models)
2. [How to design deep learning models with sparse inputs in Tensorflow Keras](https://medium.com/dailymotion/how-to-design-deep-learning-models-with-sparse-inputs-in-tensorflow-keras-fd5e754abec1)
3. [Neural network for sparse matrices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-demographics/discussion/22567)
4. [Training Neural network with scipy sparse matrix?](https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification/discussion/18154)
5. [Documentation of `sparse` library](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable - Getting this error

Comment: See the section **`Sparse Matrix from 3D non-sparse input matrix`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `np.reshape`

https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

```
other_features_train = other_features_train.reshape(other_features_train.shape[0], other_features_train.shape[1], 1)

other_features_cv = other_features_cv.reshape(other_features_cv.shape[0], other_features_cv.shape[1], 1)

other_features_test = other_features_test.reshape(other_features_test.shape[0], other_features_test.shape[1], 1)
```

Also, you need to change this line

`input_model_2 = Input(shape=(101, 1),name='other_features')`

Conv1D expects 3-d data, not 2-d.

Comment: I have tried this, but am getting error with this.ValueError: matrix shape must be two-dimensional

Comment: The reason is simple you have 2-d input shape, as I suggested. I can clearly see there is other part of code `compile`, where the error occurs, if you don't post that part, will be hard to detect the issue. Check the updated answer.